# Create nested Json data according Html structure

Tags: jquery, json, dynamic

I am working on a custom Jquery query builder, i have completed the UI part with all fields and nesting elements, now i am getting stuck while exporting the data in Json format in same nesting (inherited as i have in HTML).

For e.g. my HTML code is

```
<div class="query">
  <input type="text" value="Field 1">
    <div class="query">
      <input type="text" value="Field 2">
      <div class="query">
        <input type="text" value="Field 3">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="query">
      <input type="text" value="Field 4">
   </div>
</div>
```

Required output in Json format as

```
     {
   "rules":[
      {
         "field":"field 1"
      },
      {
         "rules":[
            {
               "field":"field 2"
            },
            {
               "rules":[
                  {
                     "field":"field 3"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "rules":[
            {
               "field":"field 4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

how can i create the required Json data in Jquery?

Comment: Please try something then let us know what you've gotten stuck on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a recursive function:

```js
function build($query) {
    return {
        rules: $.map($query.children("input, .query"), function (item) {
            return $(item).is("input") ? { field: $(item).val() } : build($(item));
        })
    };
}

const result = build($(".query:first"));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="query">
    <input type="text" value="Field 1">
    <div class="ignorethis">
        <input type="text" value="Field to ignore">
    </div>
    <div class="query">
        <input type="text" value="Field 2">
        <div class="query">
            <input type="text" value="Field 3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="query">
        <input type="text" value="Field 4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Trincot for the quick response, just want to know that in between Html structure if we have any another class like <div class="accord"><div class="query">.... then how can we ignore element with accord class so that it does not treat as a another nested element.

Comment: You can add a filter to the `children` method call. I updated the snippet adding such a filter.